windows defender antivirus folder missing on local group policy editor

gpedit.msc was missing, i added it with using .bat
after restart i could enter to gpedit.msc but windows defender antivirus folder is missing
i need that folder to disable windows defender. pls help
windows specs
Edition Windows 11 Home Single Language
Version 23H2
Installed on ‎6/‎9/‎2023
OS build 22631.3737
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1009.0

You have to install the Administrator templates yourself which might not be possible since your NOT running an edition that actually supports the local group policy editor. Worth pointing out you can’t actually disable Windows Defender through a group policy, even on Windows 11 Professional, most certainly not on Home. Group policies further restrict policies by editions and only being applied to say Education and Enterprise

You need to install the Windows 11 23H2 Administrator Template you still can’t disable Windows Defender on Home or Professional through a group policy. At least the policy will be installed.

Installing a third-party AV disables Defender. However, as Administrator, you should be able to temporarily turn off real-time AV protection. Permanently disabling all AV is inadvisable -- except for scammers looking to take over a PC.


but windows defender antivirus folder is missing i need that folder to disable windows defender.

It’s not possible to disable Windows Defender on Windows Home Single Language. DisableAntiSpyware and DisableAntivirus no longer works on any supported versions of Windows 10 or Windows 11.
Source: DisableAntiSpyware
However, in order to manage the Windows Defender group policies, regardless of which edition of Windows you are running, requires you to install the Administrator templates.
Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 11 2023 Update (23H2)

Windows # Home editions do not come with a group policy editor. Adding one back in doesn't mean it magically works. You miss certain features, which means you miss the admx templates.
As Home verions are not supported for group policy, my suggestion is going to be: upgrade to Windows 11 Pro.

It’s not possible to disable Windows Defender on Home or Professional. So upgrading would just be a waste of money. Many group policies are only applicable to Enterprise and Education that disabled features like Windows Defender but there is a lot of outdated information on how to disable Windows Defender.

@Ramhound if you install another virus scanner, it disables windows defender automatically though...

It doesn’t fully disable it. That is the closest way of disabling it in my experience.
